# Java Method Not Found, even though method signature looks OK (desmo-j simulation)

Tags: java, signature

I'm trying to run the Desmo-J simulation sample in Java, NetBeans 7.2 on a Mac OS X 10.7.
A class called TimeSeries is included as an import ie.

```
import desmoj.core.statistic.TimeSeries;
```

It has a function signature of

```
(Model, String, TimeInstant,TimeInstant, boolean)
```

I can **compile** my main java file OK, but when **running/debugging**, it fails, telling me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: desmoj.core.statistic.TimeSeries.<init>(Ldesmoj/core/simulator/Model;Ljava/lang/String;Ldesmoj/core/simulator/TimeInstant;Ldesmoj/core/simulator/TimeInstant;Z)V
```

This is despite the fact the call I'm making (AFAIK) passes exactly the right typed parameters:

```
trucksArrived = new TimeSeries(this.getModel(), "arrived", new TimeInstant(0), new TimeInstant(1500), false);
trucksServiced = new TimeSeries(this.getModel(), "finished", new TimeInstant(0), new TimeInstant(1500), false);
```

I'm stumped as to why this might be happening. **Any clues on why Java would be unable to recognise my method call at runtime, while seeing it fine in the compile?**
Could it be something interfering on the classpath ie. another TimeSeries out there (can't see any at the moment in the libs)? Have I read the exception message (with its function signature) properly? Some of the methods in TimeSeries are deprecated (though not the ones I'm using). Could that interfere with things perhaps?

Thanks guys
Pete

Comment: I am confused, is it a method or a constructor?

Comment: And TimeInstannt is imported correctly, too> And it has a one-arg constructor?

Comment: Show the method in question, in context of the class

Comment: @Abu - it's a method, @ Chris Gerken - yep Timeinstant is OK (I can instantiate them separately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use a constructor with the signature:

> TimeSeries(Model, String, TimeInstant, TimeInstant, boolean)

which should match [this one](http://desmoj.sourceforge.net/doc/desmoj/core/statistic/TimeSeries.html#TimeSeries%28desmoj.core.simulator.Model,%20java.lang.String,%20desmoj.core.simulator.TimeInstant,%20desmoj.core.simulator.TimeInstant,%20boolean%29).

The fact that your compile is succeeding but the program is giving this runtime error strongly suggest that your application is using a different version of the library at runtime than the version that you compiled against.  Check the following:

- Check that you have the same desmoj JAR on your build classpath and your run classpath.
- Check that you haven't accidentally included two versions of the desmoj JAR on either classpath.

Comment: Javap is a useful tool in confirming this, javap -classpath same-classpath-you-use-to-run-java com.theclass.that.gives.AnError

Comment: Beyond that, check System.getProperty("java.class.path") to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C and Ricky - I'll check both those things and post back. I must admit, I was a bit suss about the JAR's on the path as the only 'difference' was the compile vs. run environments.

Comment: OK found the problem: TimeSeries clashes with an included library's TimeSeries (jFreeChart). Solution was to rename the desmo-j TimeSeries. Unfortunately complete specification of the class ie. referring to it as desmoj.core.statistic.TimeSeries didn't help, but renaming it all together does resolve it. Thanks again guys.

Comment: @Pete855217 - If you consistently referred to `desmoj.core.statistic.TimeSeries` by its FQN, it *should* work.  I suspect that the problem was that you didn't find all occurrences.